# Why "Führerschein" instead of "Fahrerschein"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

**Führen** means lead or guide. **Führer** is leader. **Führerschein** is, however, *driving license*. For driving, there is a *more suitable* word: **fahren**. So I expect driving license should be **Fahrerschein**.

Is there any interesting interpretation behind **Führerschein** (e.g. historical context, cultural thingy, root word), or it is just what it is?

Comment: *Der Führer ist ein armes Schwein, denn er hat keinen Führerschein* [Brösel, 1981]

Comment: *führen* actually has a lot more meanings than just "lead or guide". You might want to consult a good dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because German traffic legislation doesn't traditionally know anything about a "Fahrer". He's called a *Kraftfahrzeugführer*. (Probably because "fahren" doesn't necessarily mean "to steer" only, but also applies to passengers [*Mitfahrer*] - Wir *fahren* mit der Bahn, obwohl wir keine Lokführer sind - this is different to "to drive" in English).

Excerpt from the *Straßenverkehrsgesetz §2*:

> Wer auf öffentlichen Straßen ein Kraftfahrzeug führt (sic), bedarf der Erlaubnis (Fahrerlaubnis) der zuständigen Behörde (Fahrerlaubnisbehörde). Die Fahrerlaubnis wird in bestimmten Klassen erteilt. Sie ist durch eine amtliche Bescheinigung (Führerschein) nachzuweisen.

(This is a relatively early law. More current legislation from the 21st century does, indeed, mainly use the term "Fahrer")

Austrian German and Swiss German help themselves by occasionally using *Lenker* and *Chauffeur* (but "Fahrer" as well) which are more specific.

You should indeed look up *führen* (which is the *[Kausativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kausativ)* of *fahren* and has the root notion of "etwas zum Fahren/Bewegen veranlassen" - It has a lot more meanings than just "lead or guide" - in a good dictionary. [Whereas yet again *fahren* has a lot more meanings than just "to drive"])

Comment: Zudem wurden früher die Wagen von Tieren gezogen, und diese wurden geführt.

Comment: The legal jargon knows about a "Fahrerlaubnis" ("Fahr-Erlaubnis", "permission to drive"), though ;) The "Führerschein" is the physical document (for example a plastic card) that confirms the legal authorization to operate a vehicle in public space. See [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BChrerschein): "Ein Führerschein oder ein Führerausweis ist eine amtliche Bescheinigung, die ein Vorhandensein einer Fahrerlaubnis zum Führen bestimmter Fahrzeuge auf öffentlichem Verkehrsgrund belegt."

Comment: But I mostly agree with your answer, especially since the term "Führerschein" [was coined in the early 20th century](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschichte_des_F%C3%BChrerscheins). In this period, "führen" in the sense of "to control the movents and actions of something or somebody else" was a popular concept. The Nazis didn't fall in love with the term out of thin air ;) So it makes sense that the new term for the new concept used terminology that was "en vouge" at the time.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck A better source for *Führerschein* vs. *Fahrerlaubnis*: *Wer auf öffentlichen Straßen ein Kraftfahrzeug führt, bedarf der Erlaubnis (Fahrerlaubnis) der zuständigen Behörde (Fahrerlaubnisbehörde). Die Fahrerlaubnis wird in bestimmten Klassen erteilt. Sie ist durch eine amtliche Bescheinigung (Führerschein) nachzuweisen.* (StVG, §2)

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: It should also be noted that "Führerschein" is not a completely singular oddity. The term "Führer" as the one controlling a vehicle or other machine has "survived" in some other words, as well, such as "Führerhaus" and "Führerstand".

Comment: It's the same reason that the union of truck drivers in USA are called the Teamsters union - Teamsters were the "drivers/*leaders*" of a team of horses, that would pull the cart/wagon/load etc.  This carried over into the motor vehicle age.